# Troubleshooting "Class 'CMap' not found" Error in Yii Project

Tags: php, yii, autoload, laragon

I'm trying to set up an older Yii project on my local environment (using Laragon), and I'm encountering the following error:
Fatal error: During inheritance of IteratorAggregate: Uncaught Error: Class "CMap" not found in C:\laragon\www\yii\framework\web\CHttpRequest.php:5.6

I've checked the PHP version compatibility, and it meets the requirements specified in my project's composer.json file.I ran composer install to ensure that all Composer dependencies are correctly installed.I verified that the Composer autoloading rules are correctly defined in my composer.json file.I checked my Yii configuration files (config/main.php, config/console.php, etc.) to ensure they are properly set up.